# Stack applet was not starting automatically

Tags: applet, startup, autostart, stackapplet

I am using stackapplet v1.4 it's not getting started automatically.Every time i want to start it manually from **Application>>Accessories>>StackApplet**.I am sure i have enabled the option **Start StackApplet during login** but it's not working.What's going wrong here?

**~/.xsession-errors** [shows the following result](http://paste.ubuntu.com/540353/).
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open up `~/.config/autostart/stackapplet.desktop`, verify that it is the same as this:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Exec=python /usr/share/stackapplet/stackapplet.py
Icon=/usr/share/pixmaps/stackapplet.png
Terminal=false
Comment=a panel indicator for monitoring StackExchange sites
Name=StackApplet
Categories=Utility;
```

The problem is likely with the `Exec` line, if you used to be using an older version that had a different `Exec` command.

Even if they are the same, try removing that file. Then un-check and re-check the `Start Stackapplet during login` checkbox.

**UPDATE:** Looking at your `~/.xsession-errors`, StackApplet needs internet access to work. If you aren't connected to the internet right away on login, you'll need to delay StackApplet from starting before you have connected to the internet.
Paste the following in a file called `.stackapplet-start.sh` in your home folder:

```
#!/bin/bash
sleep 30 && python /usr/share/stackapplet/stackapplet.py
```

Make that file executable:

```
chmod a+x ~/.stackapplet-start.sh
```

Now open *System -> Preferences -> Startup Applications*, edit the `StackApplet` entry and change the `Command:` to `/home/<USERNAME>/.stackapplet-start.sh`.

Comment: Yep it has the same line.

Comment: @karthick87 Open up ~/.xsession-errors and search for anything related to `stackapplet.desktop`

Comment: Eventually this won't be an issue - the app will still start up without Internet access. But that hasn't been fixed yet :)

Comment: This is now fixed. The application should start regardless.

Answer (score 0):

verify that it appears in the startup application: **System** > **Preferences** > **Startup Applications**.

If it is not there , create a launcher, and add it.

--  Yonatan

Comment: Yes it's there in startup list

Comment: what's the entries command?

Comment: python /usr/share/stackapplet/stackapplet.py