# Unable to add the Stackapplet to panel

Tags: 10.10, gnome-panel, stackapplet

I'm running Ubuntu 10.10, and am trying to add the [StackApplet](https://stackapps.com/questions/83/stackapplet-stackoverflow-meets-the-gnome-desktop) to the panel.

The steps I'm following are, just to be sure I'm not doing something obviously wrong:

1. Right-click on the top panel
2. Click 'Add to Panel'
3. Select 'StackApplet' from the menu dialogue that appears.

Doing this causes a small, roughly 1px<sup>2</sup>, grey square to be added to the panel, but with no indication of *why* the StackApplet isn't responding/loading. I've tried adding to the panel, then restarting `gdm` and also adding to the panel and then restarting the system. Neither approach seemed to achieve anything.

I've also completely removed/purged, and then reinstalled, StackApplet via Synaptic in the hope that might fix any dependency issues, to no avail..

Obviously there is further information needed to answer this question, but at this stage I don't know enough about *what* information might be needed, or, in most cases, how to *find* it. I'll do my best to add any information requested in comments, though, to try and solve this.

My thanks in advance, for any and all help and guidance anyone can offer...

---

Questions I've read through prior to asking:

- [Stack applet was not starting automatically](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16408/stack-applet-was-not-starting-automatically)

  - Don't seem to have the file: `~/.xsession-errors`
  - Didn't have, but did create, the file `~/.config/autostart/stackapplet.desktop` with the contents suggested in the accepted answer.
- [Can't add to panel nor delete panel](https://askubuntu.com/questions/29329/cant-add-to-panel-nor-delete-panel)

  - Haven't tried reinstalling `gnome-panel`, yet, mainly because I've read elsewhere that this may cause a world of pain. If that's wrong, I'll happily give it a go, though.
- [How can I add the Network Manager Applet to the panel after removing?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1974/how-can-i-add-the-network-manager-applet-to-the-panel-after-removing)

  - Tried re-adding the notification area to the panel, which worked (in that it added the notifcation area), but didn't resolve the StackApplet problem.

---

**Edited** in response to @EvilPhoenix's answer:

> StackApplet is run via a different system. run StackApplet from Applications > Accessories. It will then turn itself on then put itself automatically into the system tray

I don't appear to have StackApplet available in the Accessories menu:

[image: Screenshot showing the Applications > Accessories menu.]

Though I *do* have StackApplet installed (according, at least, to the Ubuntu Software Centre):

[image: Screenshot of the Software Centre, showing StackApplet is installed.]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that you are running an older version of StackApplet that is no longer supported and doesn't quite work as well.

You can find the new version (1.4.1 beta) in the [StackApplet PPA](https://launchpad.net/~stackapplet-dev/+archive/stackapplet).

- [What are PPAs and how do I use them?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4983/what-are-ppas-and-how-do-i-use-them)

Comment: ... *ah* that'd do it, then; +1 and accepted, Mr Edison, and thank you for a wonderful applet! =D

Comment: @David: You're welcome. Glad you got it working.

Answer (score 3):

StackApplet is run via a different system.  run StackApplet from Applications > Accessories.  It will then turn itself on then put itself automatically into the system tray.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't seem to have StackApplet available via the Applications > Accessories menu. Though it **is** installed, according to Ubuntu Software Centre (see edits to question for demonstration and information). :(

Comment: After adding the PPA (as per @George Edison's answer), your solution worked, but I think the greater part of it was George's, but, sincerely, thank you for your help! =]

Answer (score 2):

You may need to reboot in order to gain access to the Applications/Accesories/StackApplet. It worked for me. Give it a try and please inform.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you, I'm not sure quite how much the reboot contributed to the solution, since I also installed the updated PPA (as per @George Edison's answer), but +1 nonetheless, thank you for your help =]